# Breaking an equation

Tags: align

How to move the second line little steps to the right such that the equal sign `=` comes down the first circle `o`. 
[image]

Here is my trial:

```
\begin{align*}
\left( \phi_{[c_{ij}]} \circ \tilde{\mu} \circ (\phi_{[a_{ij}]}\times 
\phi_{[b_{i^{\prime}j^{\prime}}]} )^{-1} \right ) 
\left( x_{11},\ldots,x_{nn},y_{11}\ldots,y_{nn} \right)
\\= \left(\phi_{[c_{ij}]} \circ \tilde{\mu} \circ (\phi_{[a_{ij}]}
\times \phi_{[b_{i^{\prime}j^{\prime}}]} )^{-1}   \right) 
\left( \phi_{[a_{ij}]}([x_{ij}])\times \phi_{[b_{i^{\prime}j^{\prime}}]}([y_{ij}])  \right)
\end{align*}
```

I need help please. Thanks in advance.

Comment: please make a small document that shows what you have done, it is impossible to guess from the fragment, what environment have you used? (one of the amsmath ones?)  most do not allow blank lines, does your real source have a blank line before `\\ ` ?

Comment: `j^{\prime}` can more simply be written as `j'`

Comment: Oh sorry, I edited the post. I use align environment.

Comment: Anyway, `j^{\prime}` is not the problem. @DavidCarlisle

Comment: Indeed, my source does not contain a blank line, otherwise I would get a compilation error. I just typed a blank line for clarity. @DavidCarlisle

Comment: It's more helpful if the example is complete from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}` to save anyone helping having to guess the required setup, but  do I understand correctly that you want to align the o in the first line with the `=` in the second?, It is certainly possible but sounds a very strange request so I thought I'd check first that is what you meant.

Comment: What you guessed is precisely what I meant. This is first.
Second, what is helpful in typing the whole code beginning with `\begin{document}` and ending with `\end{document}` ?! I just typed the part of the code we are concerning about, and I think this is enough.

Comment: a blank line generates a tex error so it makes the example completely unclear. that is why it is always best to make a complete document and post the image generated by that test document.

Comment: No it is really unhelpful not to provide the whole document, firstly it makes everyone offering to help have to guess the needed packages and type out the preamble, and it would allow _you_ to test the posted code and not post code that generates tex errors unrelated to your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the alignment seems very strange as there is no mathematical relationship between the operator and the =, but

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\bigl( \phi_{[c_{ij}]} &\circ \tilde{\mu} \circ (\phi_{[a_{ij}]}\times 
\phi_{[b_{i'j'}]} )^{-1} \bigr) 
( x_{11},\ldots,x_{nn},y_{11}\ldots,y_{nn} )
\\
&= \bigl(\phi_{[c_{ij}]} \circ \tilde{\mu} \circ (\phi_{[a_{ij}]}
\times \phi_{[b_{i'j'}]} )^{-1}   \bigr) 
\bigl( \phi_{[a_{ij}]}([x_{ij}])\times \phi_{[b_{i'j'}]}([y_{ij}])\bigr)
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

It is hard to guess any possible meaning for the alignment here. If the real intention is just a multiline equation with the first line flush left and the last flush right, with no alignment points then

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{multline*}
\bigl( \phi_{[c_{ij}]} \circ \tilde{\mu} \circ (\phi_{[a_{ij}]}\times 
\phi_{[b_{i'j'}]} )^{-1} \bigr) 
( x_{11},\ldots,x_{nn},y_{11}\ldots,y_{nn} )
\\
= \bigl(\phi_{[c_{ij}]} \circ \tilde{\mu} \circ (\phi_{[a_{ij}]}
\times \phi_{[b_{i'j'}]} )^{-1}   \bigr) 
\bigl( \phi_{[a_{ij}]}([x_{ij}])\times \phi_{[b_{i'j'}]}([y_{ij}])\bigr)
\end{multline*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `multline` seems more likely

Comment: @egreg yes I was wondering if that was the real intention, I'll add an example..

Comment: @egreg two versions posted:-)

Comment: Thanks sir @DavidCarlisle , this works fine. I appreciate your help :) .

Answer (score 2):

Using `\Bigl( … \Bigr)` you can align as you want, and have a better spacing of parentheses. You also can use a simple `multline` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  \Bigl( \phi_{[c_{ij}]} &  \circ \tilde{\mu }  \circ (\phi_{[a_{ij}]} \times
  \phi_{[b_{i^{\prime}j^{\prime}}]} )^{-1} \Bigr)
  \Bigl( x_{11},\ldots,x_{nn},y_{11}\ldots,y_{nn} \Bigr)
  \\&= \Bigl(\phi_{[c_{ij}]}  \circ \tilde{\mu }  \circ (\phi_{[a_{ij}]}
   \times  \phi_{[b_{i^{\prime}j^{\prime}}]} )^{-1}   \Bigr)
  \Bigl( \phi_{[a_{ij}]}([x_{ij}]) \times  \phi_{[b_{i^{\prime}j^{\prime}}]}([y_{ij}])  \Bigr)
\end{align*}

\begin{multline*}
  \Bigl( \phi_{[c_{ij}]}   \circ \tilde{\mu }  \circ (\phi_{[a_{ij}]} \times
  \phi_{[b_{i^{\prime}j^{\prime}}]} )^{-1} \Bigr)
  \Bigl( x_{11},\ldots,x_{nn},y_{11}\ldots,y_{nn} \Bigr)
  \\ = \Bigl(\phi_{[c_{ij}]}  \circ \tilde{\mu }  \circ (\phi_{[a_{ij}]}
   \times  \phi_{[b_{i^{\prime}j^{\prime}}]} )^{-1}   \Bigr)
  \Bigl( \phi_{[a_{ij}]}([x_{ij}]) \times  \phi_{[b_{i^{\prime}j^{\prime}}]}([y_{ij}])  \Bigr)
\end{multline*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: the posted code would not produce any binary operators in the output.

Comment: @David Carlisle: I see… It's my editor ( sort of pretty-displaying — no Greek letters, though).

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough reputation to comment but I use the symbol '&' to tell the `align` environment how to align the lines with respect to each other.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\Bigl( \phi_{[c_{ij}]} &\circ \tilde{\mu} \circ 
    (\phi_{[a_{ij}]}\times \phi_{[b_{i'j'}]} )^{-1} \Bigr) 
    \Bigl( x_{11},\ldots,x_{nn},y_{11}\ldots,y_{nn} \Bigr) \\
&= \Bigl(\phi_{[c_{ij}]} \circ \tilde{\mu} \circ 
    (\phi_{[a_{ij}]}\times \phi_{[b_{i'j'}]} )^{-1} \Bigr) 
    \Bigl( \phi_{[a_{ij}]}([x_{ij}])\times 
    \phi_{[b_{i'j'}]}([y_{ij}])  \Bigr)
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I attempted this and it does not work, a compilation error arise due to the symbol & preceding o

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can improve the answer by removing those useless `\left` and `\right`; also `j'` is much clearer than `j^{\prime}`

Comment: But I need `\left` and `\right` to generate much larger braces. Your note does not seem to be a solution of the problem.

Comment: I can only assume you have not tested this answer as you can not use `&` where you suggest .

Comment: The posted code does not compile for me.

Comment: @HusseinEid You should think whether you *do* need bigger parentheses in the first place. You don't.

Comment: Yes, I was just giving an idea because I always use the '&' to align my equation as I want and never got any problem doing so. 
I don't have LaTeX right now and wanted to propose this as a comment (which I cannot do, as stated in my answer...)
So, yeah the code might not compile, my point was only to specify this '&' trick :)

Comment: I edited, the code should work now. I least it does for me and the alignment matches with what specified in the question.

Comment: @Eskapp We prefer to have sound answer; checking the solution should be a habit.

Comment: I agree, but sometimes just an idea to unlock. Once again, I really wanted this to be a comment as I couldn't check it (I should have precised though I agree, sorry about this). Anyways, I found a solution to have it run ;)

Comment: @Eskapp - I've taken the liberty of converting your code snippet into a fully compilable LaTeX document and adding a screenshot. Please advise if you're not OK with this.

Comment: @Mico - This is perfect, I'll keep this in mind next time I post an answer :) Many thanks!